# Silverstripe Test not Injecting config for Element

Tags: php, phpunit, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

For some reason my test isn't injecting `MockFormElement::$controller_class`

My Test:

```php
class NestedElementForms extends FunctionalTest {
    protected static $fixture_file = 'NestedElementFormsFixture.yml';

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function submitFormOnElement() {
        $this->assertEquals(MockFormElementController::class, MockFormElement::config()->controller_class, 'Injection failed');
    }
}
```

My Mock Element:

```php
class MockFormElement extends BaseElement implements TestOnly
{   
    private static $controller_class = MockFormElementController::class;
}

class MockFormElementController extends ElementController implements TestOnly
{

}
```

I've tried `dev/build` and clearing the silverstripe cache with `rm -rf /tmp/silverstripe-...` with no luck. It keeps it default value `'DNADesign\Elemental\Controllers\ElementController'`

Comment: Could this be a namespacing issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use test only data objects in a test one needs to explicitly include them in the `$extra_dataobjects` config of that test

Answer (score 0):

Try flush during your PHPUnit execution:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit app/tests/ flush=1
```

The config of `TestOnly` classes can be occluded from SilverStripe's cache.